# Transparent Buttons in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, button, transparent, operating-system

I'm trying to create a transparent button in my iPhone app -- to create an Easter Egg of sorts. How would I go about setting the button to be transparent without touching the alpha (when alpha = 0.0 on a UIButton, it no longer responds to touch)?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the alpha to a very small value.

Or, you could create a blank, clear UIImage and use a custom button style, and set it to the button's image.

Comment: Dangit chpwn, trying to take my stack overflow answers! It's ok, my way is better :)

Answer (score 14):

Set your button type to UIButtonTypeCustom and it will have no styling. (thus, it should be "invisible").

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for! Thank you!

Comment: Perfect! Although, now it's 2013, so you just click the `Attributes Inspector`, and change your button's `Type` to `Custom`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var btnTest = Ti.UI.createButton({
    backgroundImage: 'sample.png',
    height: 24,
    width: 20,
    top:  10,
    left:10
});
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Objective C?

Comment: Ah, I see - this snippet uses the Titanium UI library, which is JavaScript-based.